# Directing Python to look in another folder for modules

Tags: python, pip, python-module

I'm still pretty new to python so forgive me if this is extremely simple or extremely the wrong way of thinking about this.

I have python 2.7 installed. From what I understand when I run the following code, it lists the directories where it looks for modules.

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct 11 2016, 14:42:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/readline
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I have another directory that appears to have a bunch of python modules I installed in it. "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages"

I guess I need to do one of two things:

(1) direct python to look in this additional folder for modules. **How do I do that?**

(2) install the modules in one of the folders it is already directing to. I've been using pip to install modules, and I think pip is installing to this additional director. **How do I check if pip is installing to this folder? How do I change where pip install packages to?**

Thanks!

Comment: A quick fix is to just append directories to `sys.path` in your code, e.g. `sys.path.append('/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages')`. This should be done before doing `import`s which rely on this directory.

Comment: to see where any given library installed with pip is located use the pip show command: `C:\Users\...>pip show numpy` look for the line `location:`

Comment: thanks, @jmd_dk, that works for me!  Thanks. Any way to tell it to permanently refer to this directory, rather than having to put in my code?

Comment: @user1500158 add it to the [system PYTHONPATH variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This stuff is setup by [`site.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html).  You can find out which `site.py` by entering the interpreter with:

```
python -v
```

Alternatively, import `site` in the interactive interpreter and check the `site.__file__` attribute.

There's also a helpful script in `site.py` which you can run with

```
python -m site
```

What you want to see in the output there is your user site, something like

```
USER_BASE: '/home/<your_username>/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/<your_username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

When you `pip install` a package, use `pip install --user`, which will install modules to your user space.  **Don't install stuff with `sudo pip install`.**  Don't munge the `sys.path` manually like the "quick fix" from [jmd_dk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982880/directing-python-to-look-in-another-folder-for-modules/40983129#comment69175602_40982880) suggests.  **Do it properly.**

If, after reading the [site documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE) and [PEP370](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/), you are still having trouble setting up the user site correctly, then it is acceptable to add a line like this in your bash profile:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/<your_username>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

If you have both a Python 3 and a Python 2 installation, beware that the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable will be seen by both interpreters.  In this case, it is strongly recommend to enable the `site.USER_SITE` separately for each interpreter (or use virtual environments) to provide adequate namespacing of installed packages.

Comment: thanks for the info.  I didn't know adding sudo to the front of that line of code "put the module in the wrong place". Am I thinking about this correctly?

Comment: Yeah, you're thinking about it incorrectly.  You should install python modules with your user account, not with the root account.  And `jmd_dk` comment is harmful, if I was a moderator I would delete it.